# svg format not accepted and not readable { expected

Tags: svg, sass, stenciljs

I have a problem while loqding the svg element.I t always show me that I need an expected element after starting the group element.It was working and when I migrated stenciljs to 1.3.1, this error appears .....
Any help

```
$icon-info-svg: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path
       d="M -3,2 H 21 V 26 H -3 Z"
       id="path5356"
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd" />
    //error is here <g
       transform="translate(3.0054614,-2.999963)"
       id="g5924">
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:%233b66e5;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"
         id="path5358"
         d="M 5.374,7.867 A 8,8 0 0 0 9,23 8,8 0 1 0 9,7" />
      <g
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:%233b66e5;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"
         id="g5362"
         transform="translate(0,6)">
          <path
             id="path5360"
             d="m 9,9 v 4 M 9,5 v 1" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>';


m expected scss(css-termexpected)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Data URL is a URL.  If you have characters in there that have a meaning in URLs, they need to be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Eg. '/', '?', '=', '#', ' ' (space) etc.